# GetFeatureInfo is not working with GeoServer point line sources

Tags: geoserver, point, layers, line, getfeatureinfo

I'm not able to get information with a GetFeatureInfo request when clicking on point and line layers. For polygons it works fine.

I'm using the code below to execute the WMS service:

```js
google.maps.event
    .addListener(
        map,
        "click",
        function(event) {
            // event.latLng.lng() + "%2C" + event.latLng.lat() + "%2C" +  event.latLng.lng() + "%2C" + event.latLng.lat() 
            var myLatLng = event.latLng;
            var lat = myLatLng.lat();
            var lng = myLatLng.lng();
            //var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            //var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));

            //var bbox = lat + "," + lng + "," + lat    + "," + lng;
            var projectionMap = new MercatorProjection();
            var point = projectionMap
                .fromLatLngToPoint(event.latLng);

            var lULP = new google.maps.Point(point.x * 256, (point.y + 1) * 256);
            var lLRP = new google.maps.Point((point.x + 1) * 256,point.y * 256);

            var lULg = projectionMap.fromDivPixelToSphericalMercator(lULP,  8);
            var lLRg = projectionMap.fromDivPixelToSphericalMercator(lLRP, 8);
            var lUL_Latitude = lULg.y;
            var lUL_Longitude = lULg.x;
            var lLR_Latitude = lLRg.y;
            var lLR_Longitude = lLRg.x;
            //GJ: there is a bug when crossing the -180 longitude border (tile does not render) - this check seems to fix it
            if (lLR_Longitude < lUL_Longitude) {
                lLR_Longitude = Math.abs(lLR_Longitude);
            }
            var bbox = lUL_Longitude + "," + lUL_Latitude + "," + lLR_Longitude + "," + lLR_Latitude;


            var projection = map.getProjection();
            var ulw = projection.fromPointToLatLng(lULP);
            var lrw = projection.fromPointToLatLng(lLRP);

            $.ajax({
                "url" : 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/WORKSPACE_X/wms?LAYERS=WORKSPACE_X:LAYER_X&QUERY_LAYERS=WORKSPACE_X:LAYER_X&STYLES=&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&BBOX='+bbox+'&FEATURE_COUNT=10&HEIGHT=539&WIDTH=1803&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&INFO_FORMAT=text%2Fhtml&SRS=EPSG%3A900913&X='+Math.round(point.x)+'&Y='+Math.round(point.y),
                //"url" : url,
                "data" : "",
                "type" : "POST",
                "success" : function(data) {

                    infowindow.setContent(data);
                    infowindow
                            .setPosition(event.latLng);
                    infowindow.open(map);
                },
                "error" : function(xhr, status,
                        error) {
                    alert(" Can't do because: "
                            + error);
                }
            });
        });
```

...

```js
/* 
     Document   : wms.js
     Created on : Feb 16, 2011, 3:25:27 PM
     Author     : "Gavin Jackson <Gavin.Jackson@csiro.au>"
     Refactored code from http://lyceum.massgis.state.ma.us/wiki/doku.php?id=googlemapsv3:home
*/

function bound(value, opt_min, opt_max) {
    if (opt_min != null)
        value = Math.max(value, opt_min);
    if (opt_max != null)
        value = Math.min(value, opt_max);
    return value;
}
function degreesToRadians(deg) {
    return deg * (Math.PI / 180);
}
function radiansToDegrees(rad) {
    return rad / (Math.PI / 180);
}
function MercatorProjection() {
    var MERCATOR_RANGE = 256;
    this.pixelOrigin_ = new google.maps.Point(MERCATOR_RANGE / 2,
            MERCATOR_RANGE / 2);
    this.pixelsPerLonDegree_ = MERCATOR_RANGE / 360;
    this.pixelsPerLonRadian_ = MERCATOR_RANGE / (2 * Math.PI);
};
MercatorProjection.prototype.fromLatLngToPoint = function(latLng, opt_point) {
    var me = this;
    var point = opt_point || new google.maps.Point(0, 0);
    var origin = me.pixelOrigin_;
    point.x = origin.x + latLng.lng() * me.pixelsPerLonDegree_;
    // NOTE(appleton): Truncating to 0.9999 effectively limits latitude to
    // 89.189.  This is about a third of a tile past the edge of the world tile.
    var siny = bound(Math.sin(degreesToRadians(latLng.lat())), -0.9999,
            0.9999);
    point.y = origin.y + 0.5 * Math.log((1 + siny) / (1 - siny))
            * -me.pixelsPerLonRadian_;
    return point;
};
MercatorProjection.prototype.fromDivPixelToLatLng = function(pixel, zoom) {
    var me = this;
    var origin = me.pixelOrigin_;
    var scale = Math.pow(2, zoom);
    var lng = (pixel.x / scale - origin.x) / me.pixelsPerLonDegree_;
    var latRadians = (pixel.y / scale - origin.y) / -me.pixelsPerLonRadian_;
    var lat = radiansToDegrees(2 * Math.atan(Math.exp(latRadians))
            - Math.PI / 2);
    return new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
};
MercatorProjection.prototype.fromDivPixelToSphericalMercator = function(
        pixel, zoom) {
    var me = this;
    var coord = me.fromDivPixelToLatLng(pixel, zoom);
    var r = 6378137.0;
    var x = r * degreesToRadians(coord.lng());
    var latRad = degreesToRadians(coord.lat());
    var y = (r / 2)
            * Math.log((1 + Math.sin(latRad)) / (1 - Math.sin(latRad)));
    return new google.maps.Point(x, y);
};
```

Did someone face the same issue?

Comment: There should be no difference. It is harder to hit points and lines but you can add a &buffer= parameter and use some bigger value than the default which is 3 pixels.

Comment: I added the buffer parametre equal to 20 and increase point size in sld file, without success. 20 is it fine ? 
thx

Comment: I think that you have GeoServer installed and you can make a test for example with the sf:bugsites layer with the layer preview app. Default buffer value seems to be OK. I can't say what makes trouble for you. The request from the log is like `/geoserver/sf/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=sf%3Abugsites&STYLES&LAYERS=sf%3Abugsites&INFO_FORMAT=text%2Fhtml&FEATURE_COUNT=50&X=50&Y=50&SRS=EPSG%3A26713&WIDTH=101&HEIGHT=101&BBOX=590008.9832702996%2C4912448.481028556%2C593864.7320467269%2C4916304.229804982`

Comment: In the layer preview of GeoServer, with OpenLayer preview, I can see that it works.
I tried to replace my layer with sf:bugsites in my html file, i have the same behavior.
What i'm suspecting is the bounding box I'm calculating. I found this code, it works fine for Polygon, maybe it's not adapted to points and lines,

Comment: When I use the same bbox generate d by openlayer preview in geoserver. It works ...
This why I'm suspecting this part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be getting a bit over complex in your WMS request. You don't need to convert coordinates client side because GeoServer is really good at that! Also, changing the style of a point will not change whether you catch it, because it's still really only a point location. You want to be fuzzy in your select. The way I do it is using a Bounding Box.

Here's how I do a WMS request with a little bounding box ([see full source](https://github.com/alexgleith/tasmap.org/blob/master/app/scripts/main.js)):

```
function getFeatureWMS(layer, clickCoords) {
  log("Getting info for layer: " + layer.title, 2)
  var wms_gf_url = layer.url
  var bbox = (clickCoords.lng - 0.0001) + 
      "," + (clickCoords.lat - 0.0001) + 
      "," + (clickCoords.lng + 0.0001) + 
      "," + (clickCoords.lat + 0.0001) + ',EPSG:4326'

  var parameters = {
      service : 'WFS',
      version : '1.1.1',
      request : 'GetFeature',
      typeName : layer.meta.name,
      maxFeatures : 100,
      outputFormat : 'application/json',
      SrsName : 'EPSG:4326',
      bbox : bbox
  };
  $.ajax({
      url : wms_gf_url + L.Util.getParamString(parameters),
      dataType : 'json',
      success : handleWMSJSON(layer)
  });
}
```

Here's the actual working request:

```
https://maps.gcc.tas.gov.au/geoserver/GCC_cc/ows?service=WFS&version=1.1.1&request=GetFeature&typeName=Stormwaterpipes&maxFeatures=100&outputFormat=application%2Fjson&SrsName=EPSG%3A4326&bbox=147.24872915616035%2C-42.79936797276235%2C147.24892915616036%2C-42.79916797276234%2CEPSG%3A4326
```

Now, I realise I'm using WFS here, because it's better for these purposes. But you can do the same using WMS, like this:

```
https://wms.tidetech.org/geoserver/public/ows?service=WMS&version=1.1.1&request=GetFeatureInfo&layers=tidal_currents_bass_strait&query_layers=tidal_currents_bass_strait&feature_count=10&info_format=text%2Fjavascript&format_options=callback%3AhandleJson&SrsName=EPSG%3A4326&width=101&height=101&x=50&y=50&bbox=146.39169921875%2C-39.98445017823439%2C146.59169921875%2C-39.78445017823439&time=2016-08-21T00%3A00%3A00.000Z&callback=jQuery22106027783352390412_1473385578164&_=1473385578165
```